# Using jquery, when I click on a link, how can I refer to a select dropdown right above it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a link and I listen to the click event.  In the event handler, I want to validate that the user has actually made a choice on the select dropdown right above this link.

How can I get a reference to this select item relative to my link so I can validate it?

here is the html below. the event handler is on the click of the ".Next" link.

```
 <select class="dropdown" name="myDropdown">
 <option value="">Select Item . . .</option>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 </select>

 <br>
 <a id="Next3" class="Next" href="">Next</a>&nbsp;
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant source code? I won't be able to answer the question for this specific case without seeing the document structure.

Comment: Could you provide some more information about the structure of your page?  Do you have lots of dropdown select's or just the one above that link?  Is it nested within any other tags?

Comment: Define "above."  DOM structure and visual layout are two very different things.

Comment: @Rob W - i have updated the question with the relevant html

Comment: @SeventotheSeven - i have update the question with the relevant html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JQuery, the most specific selector looks like:

```
var reference = $("#Next3").prevAll("select.dropdown[name='myDropdown']:first")[0];
var selectedAny = reference.value != "";
```

Explanation of code:
`$("#Next3")` refers to the link with `id="Next3"`
`.prevAll()` is a function which selects all previous elements according to a selector (just`prev` doesn't work).

`select.dropdown[name='myDropdown']:first` selects the first (closest) occurence of the `select`element, which class is `dropdown` and name equals`myDropdown`(case sensitive).

Comment: the issue is that the code needs to work for any relative link and select so i can't hard code it for this instance. (thus the question)

Answer (score 1):

You can use sibling or parent selectors or a combination both but I would not recommend it since those kinds of selector tend to be fragile. When you change the structure of your html the selector might fail.

I think it would be better if you give your dropdown an id, then associate that id with the link using jquery.data().

Update:
Given the html you posted, try using the closest() filter.

e.g. in your event handler:

```
function someEventHandler() {
  $(this).closest('select.dropdown')...
}
```

If the name is known or there is only one pair of link-dropdown you can just refer to the select by name then.

Comment: the issue is that my event handler is based on a class name

Answer (score 1):

If the select is directly before the link then you can use `prev` http://api.jquery.com/prev/

If the HTML is more complicated then that you'll need to post it.

Comment: i have posted the relevant html

Comment: prev should work. Two prev may be needed to pass the br tag. $('.next').prev().prev()

Comment: @code90 - using prev() seems very hacky here as if i add a <br> at some later point the whole thing breaks

Comment: well then I think we need to see more complete html as kingjiv suggested. If you have an enclosing div tag, you could use something like: $('.next').parent().find('select:first'). but more html code will help to see the structure better to get a better answer.

Comment: or it could be $('.next').prev('select')